# Identity operator on a Hilbert B-module is compact if and only if it is a linear combination of finitely many rank-one operators.

Tags: functional-analysis, compact-operators, hilbert-modules

Recall that a Hilbert $B$-module $X$ over a $C*$-algebra $B$ is completion of a right $B$-module $E$ endowed with a $B$-valued inner product such that $(x, x) \geq 0$, $(x, x) = 0 \iff x = 0$, $(x, y)^* = (y, x)$, and $(x, yb) = (x, y)b$ for all $x, y\in X$ and $b \in B$. The completion is with respect to the norm $\|x\|_X = \|(x, x)\|_B^{1/2}$. Let $T$ be a $B$-linear map from $X$ to itself, with this $B$-valued inner product, one can define the adjoint $T^*$ in the usual sense: $(Tx, y) = (x, T^*y)$ and the norm of $T$ is the operator norm in the usual sense as well. We can define the rank-one operator $x\otimes y: z \mapsto x(y, z)$ for $x, y, z \in B$ and we write $K(X)$ to be the closed span of rank-one operators.

Now my question is that: if the identity operator $1_X$ is compact, then how to show that $1_X$ is a linear combination of finite rank-one operators? I could not find any proof of it but it seems a well-known fact that was used in many papers.

Comment: 1) Does "if $1_X$ is compact" mean "if $1_X\in K(X)$"? 2) Shouldn't "finite" be dropped in "linear combination of finite rank-one operators"? 3) Let $FR(X)$ denote the linear span of rank-one operators. Am I correct to understand your question as $1_X\in\overline{FR(X)}\Rightarrow1_X\in FR(X)?$

Comment: @AnneBauval For 1), yes. For 2), yes, if finiteness is defined in the "linear combination". For 3), that's exactly what I want to ask! Thanks for making it more clear.

Comment: Note that a $B$-linear map $T:X\to X$ does not necessarily have an adjoint, even if $T$ is bounded. $K(X)$ is defined as the closure of $RF(X)$ in the $C^*$-algebra $B(X)$ of those $T$ who do have an adjoint (after checking that the rank-one operators do).

Comment: One also easily checks that $B(X)$ is complete. This ensures that $K(X)$ also is (which is implicitely used in Ruy's answer).

Comment: @AnneBauval Thanks for pointing it out. I forgot to mention that $B(X)$ is the set of "adjointable" operators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $FR(X)$, the linear span of the rank one operators, is a dense ideal in $K(X)$.  Thus, in case $K(X)$ is unital, there is some $T\in FR(X)$, with
$$
\|T-1_X\|<1.
$$
By a well known result, $T$ must be invertible, but if an ideal contains an invertible element, it must coincide with the whole algebra.

Comment: I think it does: if you agree that my argument gives $K(X)=FR(X)$, then you must accept that $1_X\in FR(X)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think the key to this argument is to conclude that $K(X) = FR(X)$!